# FLTK in Cygwin using Eclipse (Linking errors)

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, linker-errors, fltk

I have this assignment due that requires the usage of FLTK. The code is given to us and it should compile straight off of the bat, but I am having linking errors and do not know which other libraries I need to include.

I currently have "opengl32", "fltk_gl", "glu32", and "fltk" included (-l), each of which seem to reduce the number of errors. I compiled FLTK using make with no specified options. Including all of the produced library files doesn't fix the problem, and I'm convinced that it's just some Windows specific problem.

Compile log:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project CG5 ****

make all 
Building target: CG5.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o"CG5.exe"  ./src/draw_routines.o ./src/gl_window.o ./src/my_shapes.o ./src/shape.o ./src/shapes_ui.o ./src/tesselation.o   -lopengl32 -lfltk_z -lfltk_gl -lglu32 -lfltk
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `_SelectPalette@12'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `_RealizePalette@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `_glDrawBuffer@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x20d): undefined reference to `_glReadBuffer@4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `_glGetIntegerv@8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `_glOrtho@48'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libfltk_gl.a(Fl_Gl_Window.o):Fl_Gl_Window.cxx:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `_SwapBuffers@4'
...and lots more
```

Thanks a ton for the help.

EDIT: These first few lines are obviously OpenGL related, although I'm still not sure what additional libraries need to be included.

Comment: its probably not it, but try changing the order so that -lglu32 is before the fltk libs.
Also are you certain its: -lGLU32 -lOpenGL32 rather than -lGLU -lGL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of closure, but I just booted into my Linux netbook and got it working.

```
-lfltk -lfltk_gl -lGLU -lGL -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: your makefile was written for Linux, and on Cygwin some libraries are either missing or in a different place.  You're going to have to examine the makefile, locate the missing libraries, and either move the libs to where the makefile expects them or change the makefile to look in the right place.

The libraries it needs are listed on the line starting `g++` (prepend 'lib' to the names after the `-l` flags)